# How to make the popup appear only once every certain time

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-modal

I have a popup that starts within 10 seconds of being on my website, but if I reload the page it also reappears.

I would like to know if it is possible to appear only once for the active session of the user within the web page

**HTML:**

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body text-center">
      <h3 class="text-center"  style="color:#434a4d">¡Canjea el <strong>cupón de regalo</strong> del <strong>95%</strong> de descuento<br> para tomar este curso en <strong>$ 9.99 usd!</strong><br><br>
        <a href="" target="_blank"><img src="https://ecommerce.tutorialesatualcance.com/vistas/img/plantilla/plantillaCupon.jpg" width="100%"></a>
       </h3>
       <a href="" target="_blank"><button class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-lg" style="padding:10px">CANJEAR CUPÓN</button></a>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

**JQUERY:**

```
setTimeout(function(){

 $("#myModal").modal();

},10000);
```

Comment: try using cookies or local storage if the user is a first time visitor, until he clears his cache/session/browser configurations, then he'll be considered as a first time visitor again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set value in cookie like this:

```
document.cookie = "popupShown=true; max-age=86400"; // 86400: seconds in a day
```

then check the value of the cookie you have set like this :

```
  if (document.cookie.indexOf("popupShown=true") == -1) {
            document.cookie = "popupShown=true; max-age=86400"; // 86400: seconds in a day
                setTimeout(function(){
                   $("#myModal").modal();
                  },10000);
}
```

you can set this code in `document.ready` or in `timeout` function.